# How can I get 'git status' to always use short format?

Tags: git, zsh, status

I'd like `git status` to always use the short format:

```
$ git status --short
 M file1
 M dir/file2
?? file_untracked3
?? dir/file_untracked4
```

There doesn't seem to exist a configuration option for this, and `git config --global alias.status "status --short"` does not work. I haven't managed to create an alias in *zsh* either.

How can I make `git status` to use the short format by default?

Comment: Include your ~/.gitconfig here.

Comment: Is using something like `stat` instead of `status` as an alias an option?

Comment: @Bartosz: It does not contain anything interesting regarding this problem.

Comment: Starting git 1.8.4, a tentative new feature was proposed, as a config `status.short`, which would allow you to define "`status --short`" by default, but the implementation isn't ready yet. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17282874/6309)

Comment: ... And that `status.short` config new feature is back, still for git1.8.4 (July/August 2013). See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17282874/6309)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Starting [git1.8.4 (July 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt#L42-L44), you can configure `git status` to use short by default.
See [commit 50e4f757f4adda096239c1ad60499cf606bf2c6f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50e4f757f4adda096239c1ad60499cf606bf2c6f):

> Some people always run '`git status -s`'.
>   The configuration variable `status.short` allows to set it by default.

So:

```
git config status.short true
```

And you would be all set!

---

[Ben Allred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2175350/ben-allred) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927672/how-can-i-get-git-status-to-always-use-short-format/17282874?noredirect=1#comment40380080_17282874):

> A quick test shows that **`git config status.branch true`** works as well, to show the branch information in conjunction with short-format.

---

It was reversed for a time:

[Commit 908a0e6b98e5a7c4b299b3643823bdefb4fa512e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/908a0e6b98e5a7c4b299b3643823bdefb4fa512e):

> It makes it impossible to "`git commit`" when `status.short` is set, and also "`git status --porcelain`" output is affected by `status.branch`.

But it is now back, still for git 1.8.4 (July/August 2013)

See [commit f0915cbaf476d63f72c284057680809ed24fbe0d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0915cbaf476d63f72c284057680809ed24fbe0d):

> **commit: make it work with `status.short`**
>
> With "`status.short`" set, it is now impossible to commit with status.short set, because it acts like "`git commit --short`", and it is impossible to differentiate between a status_format set by the command-line option parser versus that set by the config parser.
>
> To alleviate this problem, clear `status_format` as soon as the config parser has finished its work.
>
> Signed-off-by: Ramkumar Ramachandra

Comment: @AdamLindberg you can still use your alias though. It would be an alias for '`git status`' only ;) The point is: you now can define `git status --short` by default for all repos (global config), keep the alias `git s`, and add another alias `git st` for `git status --long`.

Comment: @AdamLindberg I spoke too soon: this feature is not yet ready (as my updated answer details).

Comment: @AdamLindberg the feature is now back for the upcoming git1.8.4

Comment: A quick test shows that `git config status.branch true` works, as well, to show the branch information in conjunction with short-format.

Comment: @BenAllred interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 36):

Use a different alias.  Instead of trying to alias 'status', do:

```
git config --global alias.s 'status --short'
```

Now "git s" gives you short output, and "git status" gives
you long output.

Comment: That is what I suggested in my comment.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may create an [alias](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases).

But I'd create bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
git status --short
```

save this script in `~/bin/gits` (or `/usr/bin/gits` and `chmod 555`), so typing `gits` gives what you want.

Comment: I would prefer not to depend on any local aliases and instead use the default `git status`.