# "git status" in brief or short format like "ls -1"?

Tags: git, git-status

I need to take a bunch of files that have changed and `scp` them to different boxes for testing. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make `git status` give me a listing like `ls -1` so I can script the actions with minimal effort.

I have an existing script that does what I need using `ls -1`. I'm not a gifted scripter, so I don't want to modify the script. Instead, I would like the tool to modify its output.

Obviously, `git status -1` did not work. The format in [How can I get 'git status' to always use short format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2927672) is not compatible with my script. And `git status --column` produced the same result as below.

How do I have `git status` list modified files, one to a line, with only the modified file on the line?

---

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   cryptest.vcproj
    modified:   dlltest.vcproj

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   adler32.cpp
    modified:   algebra.cpp
    modified:   algparam.cpp
    modified:   asn.cpp
    modified:   asn.h
    modified:   authenc.cpp
    modified:   authenc.h
    modified:   basecode.cpp
    modified:   cast.cpp
    modified:   ccm.cpp
    modified:   cmac.cpp
    modified:   config.h
    modified:   cryptdll.vcproj
    modified:   cryptlib.cpp
    modified:   cryptlib.h
    modified:   cryptlib.vcproj
    modified:   datatest.cpp
    modified:   dlltest.cpp
    modified:   eax.cpp
    modified:   ec2n.cpp
    modified:   eccrypto.cpp
    modified:   ecp.cpp
    modified:   emsa2.cpp
    modified:   eprecomp.cpp
    modified:   esign.cpp
    modified:   files.cpp
    modified:   filters.cpp
    modified:   filters.h
    modified:   fips140.cpp
    modified:   fipsalgt.cpp
    modified:   fltrimpl.h
    modified:   gf2_32.cpp
    modified:   gf2n.cpp
    modified:   gf2n.h
    modified:   gfpcrypt.cpp
    modified:   gfpcrypt.h
    modified:   hkdf.h
    modified:   hmac.cpp
    modified:   hrtimer.cpp
    modified:   ida.cpp
    modified:   idea.cpp
    modified:   integer.cpp
    modified:   iterhash.cpp
    modified:   luc.h
    modified:   misc.cpp
    modified:   misc.h
    modified:   modes.cpp
    modified:   modes.h
    modified:   nbtheory.cpp
    modified:   network.cpp
    modified:   oaep.cpp
    modified:   panama.cpp
    modified:   pkcspad.cpp
    modified:   polynomi.cpp
    modified:   pssr.cpp
    modified:   pubkey.h
    modified:   pwdbased.h
    modified:   queue.cpp
    modified:   rijndael.cpp
    modified:   rsa.cpp
    modified:   rw.cpp
    modified:   salsa.cpp
    modified:   seal.cpp
    modified:   secblock.h
    modified:   simple.h
    modified:   smartptr.h
    modified:   socketft.cpp
    modified:   socketft.h
    modified:   sosemanuk.cpp
    modified:   strciphr.cpp
    modified:   strciphr.h
    modified:   test.cpp
    modified:   validat1.cpp
    modified:   validat2.cpp
    modified:   vmac.cpp
    modified:   wait.cpp
    modified:   winpipes.cpp
    modified:   winpipes.h
    modified:   words.h
    modified:   xtr.cpp
    modified:   xtr.h
    modified:   zdeflate.cpp
    modified:   zinflate.cpp
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`git status --porcelain`

This will output in short format but will be consistent across all versions of Git.

[git-status documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status)

Here is an excerpt from the reference:

> **--porcelain** 
> Give the output in an *easy-to-parse format for scripts*. This is similar to the short output, but will remain stable across Git
>   versions and regardless of user configuration.

Comment: This still doesn't replicate the output of `ls -1`. Care to expand your answer a wee bit?

Comment: Thanks. Its close, but there are additional characters on the line. I want one file listed on one line.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can that output trimmed down anymore.  `git-status` doesn't just list files.  It gives much more information than that, so outside of shortening the output with that option your best bet (and only option, I think) is to just have custom parsing logic.

Comment: @Thomas - why does that not surprise me.... Git takes every simple tasks and makes you work for the result... I'll just award the answer to you since its another Git gap. You should not be penalized for the tool's short comings.

Comment: `git status --porcelain` outputs all differences between working directory and repository — so the untracked files too. So without some grepping your answer is incomplete.

Comment: @jww: There's a better answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35865151/1450294 I'm not sure it's appropriate to penalise Thomas for sharing the best answer he knew, but it's more appropriate than an unfair remark about git!

Answer (score 8):

If you have unstaged changes, you can list all the touched files in a one-column list similar to `ls -1` with this command:

`git ls-files --modified --others --exclude-standard --directory`

The `--modified` option shows modified files and the `--others` option shows other untracked files such as new files; `--exclude-standard` ignores excluded files and `--directory` lists only directory names and not the files inside them.  Refer to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) for more information.

Here's the command I use to quickly copy all modified and new files to my temp directory while preserving the full directory path (a dirty alternative to `git stash`):

```
git ls-files --modified --others --exclude-standard --directory | xargs -I {} cp --parents {} ~/temp
```

---

If you have already added the files to git to be committed (e.g., `git add -A .`), then you can use the command in the accepted answer and extract the second column to get your plain list of files:

`git status --porcelain | awk '{ print $2 }'`

If you want to filter the rows by git status, then you can do something like this:

`git status --porcelain | grep ^[AM] | awk '{ print $2 }'`

This gives you a list containing only modified (`M`) and newly added (`A`) files.

---

**Updates:**

- Added @jotik's suggestion.

Comment: `git ls-files --modified --others --exclude-standard --directory` might give more better output, by taking git exclusion files into account and not recursing into directories not under version control.

Answer (score 4):

For modified file list, the following commands can be a help.

`git diff --name-only`

or

`git diff --name-status`

int the output of --name-status, the status(A, M, D) and file pathname is separated by tab, you can parse it by `cut` command.

If you can to get file list on staging too, `--cache' option can be used.

Answer (score 3):

As Thomas suggested, the `--porcelain` option is the thing you want.  But of course, to get JUST the filename of modified files, you need to parse that output as well.  For example, piping the output through a simple sed script like this may work:

```
git status --porcelain | sed -ne '/^M  */s///p'
```

This script searches for a `M` and whitespace at the beginning of the line.  If they are found, they are removed and the line is printed.  If they are not found (i.e. the output is something other than a `M`odified file), no output is shown.

The output of the command line above should be just about equivalent to what you get from `ls -1` -- that is, a list of files, with no other information.  Note that `--porcelain` terminates filenames with a NULL, so if the output does not function as you expect, you may need to handle that in your script, or in another pipe.  (Read about `xargs(1)`).

Comment: Your answer doesn't cover all cases. Only fully staged files have output from `git status --porcelain` that is handled by your `sed`. If a given file was modified, but unstaged, the output would look like this" ` M an_unstaged_file` (with space at the beginning). Even better, if file had both staged and unstaged parts, the output would be `MM an_unstaged_and_staged_file`.

Answer (score -1):

To detect changed files and `scp` them directly to the remote server :

```
scp `git status --porcelain | cut -c 4-` bb:~/${PWD##*/}
```